# node.js jasmin-node script to run one spec at a time

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, jasmine

I have a bunch of jasmine-node specs in a directory. When I run jasmine-node and lets say a specific spec fails, I do not get a message on what specific spec failed. The internal error does surface up but the spec that triggered it does not show up in the stack trace.

Can anyone point to ways to resolve this? Is there a script that can run one spec at a time sequentially and fail if any individual spec fails?

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
jasmine-node --verbose
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try [humile](https://github.com/megahertz/humile) which is alternative Jasmine test runner for Node.js. It shows additional information for uncaught exceptions.